# Equivalent of function String$() VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, migration

I am migrating an application from VB6 to VB.Net, Which is using the **String$()** function.

My question is: Which is the "equivalent" of VB6 **String$()** in following Code?

```
Dim Symbol As String=""
Dim iRet As Long
iRet = GetLocaleInfo(LCID, LOCALE_SCURRENCY, lpLCDataVar, 0)
Symbol = String$(iRet, 0)
```

Note that `String$()` is the function which returns a repeating character string of the length specified:

> Syntax:
>
> ```
> String$(number, character)
> ```
>
> `number`  Length of the returned string.
>
> `character`   Required. Character
>   code specifying the character or string expression whose first
>   character is used to build the return string.

([reference](https://chennaiiq.com/developers/reference/visual_basic/functions/string.asp))

If I will remove `$`, It will give me error that **"String" is a Class and cannot used as an expression**.

[image: Check error into Image]

Comment: In VBA/VB6 functions returning a string rather than a variant have `$` as a suffix. So you can choose your function (ie `string` as a variant and `string$` as a string. Also `$` as a suffix to a variable name declares it as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code appears to be getting the currency symbol (and decimal separator) for a culture. It would be better to write it using .NET methods instead of the half-way route of using VB6 in .NET.

For example,

```vb
Imports System.Globalization

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim lcid = 2057
        Dim ci As New CultureInfo(lcid)
        Console.WriteLine(ci.EnglishName)
        Console.WriteLine(ci.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol)
        Console.WriteLine(ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

outputs

> English (United Kingdom)
>   £
>   .

There is much more information in the documentation for the [CultureInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 4):

[This `String` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_) is the correct way to create a `String` containing a specific number of a specific character, e.g.

```
Dim c = "0"c
Dim count = 10
Dim str As New String(c, count)
```

Comment: This actually answers the question posed by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent to **String$** (in older BASICs) is **StrDup** (VB.NET).

So, in your case:

```
Symbol = StrDup(iRet, Chr(0))
```